# How to change Android Gradle Plugin when using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I have Android project created using Cordova. The **build.gradle** shows:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

Is there any way to adjust this Android Gradle Plugin default to **2.2.3**?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default version by setting the `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` environment variable.

```
$ export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.3-all.zip
```

Comment: What I understand is that CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL is for the **gradle** which in this case I use
`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

That means that using CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL wont change **Android plugin for gradle**. It will only change the gradle version to **https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip** which can be seen in the gradle-wrapper file

**Android Plugin for Gradle version** is not the same as **Gradle version**
[link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)